# SUM value in active excel file and with the value from second excel file

Tags: excel, sum

As the title states thats I would like to find out how to do it.

I have two different excel files and in the first one is the original file and the second one is a formatted version from the first one.

How can I SUM the cell from file1 with the value from file2?

The value in file1 is formated to general and in the file2 as a number.

Thank for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, sure!

Open both excel files, go to the destination file and tipe in the formula you want, selecting the cells from the right file (you can move between the files WHILE you're entering the formula and the name of the cell you're adding in the formula will contain the name of the file as well:

1. type =
2. then move to the other open excel file, select a cell and type +
3. then move to another cell on another sheet or file and select it as well
4. After selecting the last cell of your formula, BEFORE you go back to the original cell that contains the formula, press ENTER: excel will terminate the formula and jump back to the original cell

Be careful: if you move or rename the satellite files/sheets, the formula will fail and you'll have to pick the external cells again.

anyway the general rule is : [Filename]SheetName!Cell  like this =[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1!$C$6

Ciao!

Comment: Thank you. It helped big time. And what to do when the cell in file2 already contains a formula?